# Swift slow compile time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compile-time, compilation-time

I have about 6 swift files with three iOS frameworks imported and compiling my projects takes about 10-15 seconds which is very slow.

I might have narrowed down it to a single swift file in my project that contains alot of code which according to the project navigater is taking more than 6 seconds to compile as opposed to the other swift files.

I chain a large amount of if else conditions in that swift file and I'm wondering if that is the reason why it takes so long to compile?

Comment: In my case, it is due to low system configuration. Whats's yours?

Comment: Macbook air 1.4GHZ 4GB ram

Comment: Frankly my system has become quite slow with 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5 4 GB RAM due to Yosemite. And this causes Xcode to open and Run projects slow.

Comment: I think its XCode bug, in 6.3.2 compile time is improved.

Comment: try sudo purge before compiling

Answer (score 1):

Adding type annotation to your variables helps compile times a lot. Most of the time is usually spent inferring the type.

```
  let foo: String = "FOO"
  let x: CGFloat = 1.0
```

In my experience adding type annotations for numeric types like `CGFloat`, `Int` is especially helpful.